# PHP: why two codes that echo the same string return different results?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new at PHP and I don't understand why this happens.I try using echo to show "$imglinksis" and the result is exactly http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg

I do not understand why the 2nd Code fails. Please help!

**Code #1**: This code completely works in returning the fields I want

```
        <?php function CallCatpicAPI($photoUrl){do something...}

$imglinksis = "http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg";
$jsonReturnCatpic = CallCatpicAPI($imglinksis);?>
```

**Code #2**: Fail to return: API says invalid URL image link

```
        <?php function CallCatpicAPI($photoUrl){do something...}?>

        <script>var img_link = "http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg";</script>

<?php
$imglinksis = "<script>document.write(img_link).toString()</script>";
$jsonReturnCatpic = CallCatpicAPI($imglinksis);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the two codes. Your php is executed on the server but the javascript is executed on the client side after php executed. You can fix your second code by this:

```
     <?php 
        $imglinksis = 'http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg';
        function CallCatpicAPI($photoUrl){do something...} 
     ?>

    <script>var img_link = '<?php echo $imglinksis; ?>';</script>

    <?php
        $jsonReturnCatpic = CallCatpicAPI($imglinksis);
    ?>
```

Comment: Yeah so in script two, you describe $imagelinksis first. Then at <script>var img_link = '<?php echo $imglinksis; ?>';</script> you echo $imglinksis which is http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg so you get <script>var img_link = "http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg";</script>

Comment: Then you can send it back to the server using ajax. There is no other way to read the local storage of a user through php. Get that value, send a request to your php file. Do your stuff and then load the results.

Comment: thank you for respond. actually the link below is pulled from local storage (already stored in browser). <script>var img_link = "http://catpic.s3.amazonaws.com/product.jpg";</script>

Comment: You welcome! Please mark the answer as solved if it solved your problem